# Sound of vowel æ

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, ae-raising

I'm reading Ann Cook's book on American Accent Training and she says:

> **æ** is a combination of the tense vowel /a:/ and lax vowel /e/

Is this a true statement? I tried hard but I couldn't glide into that. from /a:/ to /e/ in order to produce /æ/

Comment: No, that's not correct. No vowel is a combination of any other vowels. That's rather a nonsensical way of describing it. Each vowel is produced in a particular area in the oral cavity; you can't ‘combine’ them. (You should also be aware that /e/ in some IPA schemes for English is a tense vowel phoneme, phonetically /eɪ/ whereas the lax one is /ɛ/, so to call it the “lax vowel /e/” is potentially confusing or misleading too.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I put it right. **/a:/** and lax vowel **/ɛ/**. so, what are you saying is that two vowel sounds can't be made at once. but what about /eɪ/ or /oɪ/ or respectively /ey/ and /ɔy/. Is this because of **y**

Comment: Those are diphthongs: they're two separate vowels pronounced right after each other, one gliding gradually into the other. They're not pronounced _simultaneously_ or combined into one—that would indeed be impossible. You can say that a vowel is physiologically _between_ two other vowels (e.g., /ɛ/ is halfway between /i/ and /a/ in straight-up IPA because the three differ essentially only in how high in your mouth your tongue is: high for /i/, mid for /ɛ/, low for /a/); but it can't be a _combination_ of them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet for sum up: I found that æ is monophthong and can't be glided but diphthongs glidable! So this book has problems. another statement: **/ʊ/** is **ih + uh** ===> /ʊ/ is /ɪ/ + /ə/

Comment: That is another odd description. Presumably, she means that the "height" of the vowel /ʊ/ is about the same as /ɪ/, while its level of "frontness" is about the same as /ʌ/. All three sounds are monophthongs.

Comment: Are you talking about the IPA sound or the `ae` ligature as used in typesetting?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I recommend reading about North American [/æ/ tensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8a%E2%9F%A9#.C3.A6_tensing), because you can get a  tense allophone of phonemic /æ/ in words like *man* [meən] and *bath* [beəθ]. My Great Lakes accent has that, but I do not have it in similar words like *trap* so it isn’t the Northern Cities Shift where that would happen everywhere. I don’t perceive the distinct allophones I produce in *trap* versus *bath* to be phonemic, and can think of no minimal pair for it.

Comment: @tchrist Absolutely true… but I’m not sure how that relates to any of this?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Because of figuring out how to describe /æ/.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a confusing way to explain the sound of /æ/, though not categorically wrong. Like /a/, /æ/ is made with the lower jaw descended relative to other vowels. /a/ and /æ/ are both slightly nasalized. Like /e/, /æ/ is pronounced with the tongue body pulled forward (while /a/ has the tongue body in more of a neutral position). As others have pointed out, both /æ/ and /e/ pattern phonologically with the lax vowels (which only very rarely appear at the end of a word).

Comment: [/e/ is not a lax vowel. The lax vowel is  /ɛ/.](http://ic-migration.webhost.uits.arizona.edu/icfiles/ic/lsp/site/IPA/SSAE.html)

Comment: @tchrist: the symbol "e" in IPA close phonetic transcription represents a tense vowel. In phonemic transcription of specific languages, /e/ can represent vowels of various qualities. In this case, it is apparently being used to represent the  vowel phoneme found in the English word "dress," which is generally classified as phonologically lax.

Comment: @suməlic *Dress* has the lax vowel  /ɛ/, unlike *days* or *dairy* which have the tense vowel /e/.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm aware that some people use these symbols that way. They are also used in other ways. For example, [John Wells](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/03/e-and.html) used /e/ to represent the "dress" vowel. Since he was at one point the [president of the International Phonetic Association](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/history-ipa), I don't think his use of the International Phonetic Alphabet can be easily dismissed as non-standard.

Comment: @tchrist /e/ is used as a transcription symbol at the phonemic level for the mid, front, lax vowel in some older analyses (namely [Chomsky & Halle's SPE](http://ewan.website/egg-course-2/readings/spe.pdf)). See p. 176. I started to suspect that Chomsky and Halle chose the symbol because the vowel was in fact higher at the time, after watching an old movie and  noticing the way Humphrey Bogart pronounced the vowel.

Comment: Furthermore, at the phonemic level (strictly speaking) all transcription symbols are conventional and unrelated to the sound's actual pronunciation.

Comment: You do have a point about “strictly speaking”, since we could argue that /drɛs/ misrepresents the rhotic as a full trilled [r] when it is almost never more than [ɹ], let alone the commonly heard [d͡ʒɻʷɛs]. Still, everything I’ve looked at has /drɛs/ or /dɹɛs/ there, including [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dress), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dress), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dress#Pronunciation), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects).

Comment: Also Kenyon and Knott. My bottom line is that it seems perversely misleading to represent /ɛ/ with /e/ when those are completely different vowels, and when the [actual IPA uses the ɛ symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) there. This is going to confuse people to deliberately use a symbol that means something else altogether, so that when they look it up they get the wrong answer.

Comment: @tchrist neither /ɛ/ nor /e/ has phonetic substance. The actual lexical contrast is between [eɪ] and [ɛ]. However, I do agree that my notation is more prone to confusion with casual visitors to the site. fwiw, I probably would have typed /ɛ/ if I had taken more time to type my answer.